# isAlive symbol not found

Tags: java

I set a timer and during the timer(before it goes to do the task and during when it is counting) I want it to print what i put in, and after the timer is done counting(when it is ready to go do the task) i want it to be done looking for the input(Scanner.nextline()), basicly asking it to end the Scanner.nextline. When i try to use the .isAlive on the timer, it gives me an error that it cannot find the symbol even though i imported (what i think are) all the necessary classes.

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.math.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 *
 * @author Morgan Higginbotham
 */
public class JavaApplication1 extends Thread {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner ci = new Scanner(System.in);
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Next");
      }
    };
    Timer t=new Timer();
    t.schedule(task, 1000);
    while (t.isAlive()) {    //not sure what to put in my while statement
      //while the timer is counting
      System.out.println(ci.nextLine());
    }
    //when the timer is done counting and ready to do the task
  }
}
```

Comment: `java.util.Timer` is not something that "runs" or doesn't.  It is more like an alarm clock that goes off at a specified interval and executes a pre-scheduled task.  You will need to clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish; a `java.util.Timer` is probably not the correct tool.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that there is an `isAlive` method? There is something called "JavaDoc" which exists for each core class, so have you checked it? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to print something repeatedly until another thread has finished doing its stuff. You can't do that with Timer, there's no such method as `isAlive()` or anything similar.

Instead, you could use a Thread Pool and a Future:

```
private static final ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
```

In your method:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(); 
Future future = threadpool.submit(task); 

while (!future.isDone()) { 
  System.out.println("Task is not completed yet....");   
  Thread.sleep(1); //sleep for 1 millisecond before checking again }
}
```

The class `MyTask` needs to implement `Callable`:

```
public class MyTask implements Callable {
  public Object call() {
    //do stuff in thread
  }
}
```

Comment: and how could I make it so that it checks of there has been user input through the console (System.in) in the while loop?

Comment: Use your scanner is the while loop, just like you did before.